# How to get the latest available-stock value from the following data in postgresql for the respective itemname?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Refer to the following sample data.

```
|availablestock  |  itemname  |  tdate            |
|----------------|------------|-------------------|
|86              |ABC         |2020-01-29 19:44:43|
|90              |ABC         |2020-01-27 19:32:59|
|88              |ABC         |2020-01-29 19:46:35|
|100             |Soap        |2020-01-26 19:46:35|
|98              |Soap        |2020-02-29 19:46:35|
```

The following result needed-

```
|availablestock  |  itemname  |  tdate            |
|----------------|------------|-------------------|
|88              |ABC         |2020-01-29 19:46:35|
|98              |Soap        |2020-02-29 19:46:35|
```

Comment: As the answers show, this question is too terse. Explain what you want to have, so there can be no two ways to understand your question.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, The expected output has been added in the question now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT max(availablestock)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE tdate BETWEEN '2020-01-20' AND '2020-01-29'
```

Comment: Need value based on the date. If I select daterange btween 01/01/2020 and 01/30/2020 then it should return 88 because it has lastest date.

Comment: Where condition will filter out the rows and will give the maximum value falls inside your date bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `order by` and `limit`

```
SELECT availablestock FROM TABLE 
WHERE TDATE BETWEEN '2020-01-20' AND '2020-01-29' 
ORDER BY TDATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=306c79bfe25c5b5e17d054c5eae9c5fe)

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks this worked for the given example. Now, I would like to add another item in the list ie.'PQR' having value 100 on 01/29/2020 then how can I get the maximum available stock for each item on same date.

Added record in the example-
Check example - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0d93dcb9f0ca03ea2292f0e63bdd63b6

Comment: Ok ! Can you edit your question and add all the needed sample data with the expected output? @jito So that i can come up with the solution that matches all the different scenarios

Answer (score 0):

**Test Script**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Items";
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Items"
(
    "Id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    "Stock" INT NOT NULL,
    "TDate" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "Items"("Name", "Stock", "TDate") VALUES ('ABC', 86, '2020-01-29 19:44:43');
INSERT INTO "Items"("Name", "Stock", "TDate") VALUES ('ABC', 90, '2020-01-27 19:32:59');
INSERT INTO "Items"("Name", "Stock", "TDate") VALUES ('ABC', 88, '2020-01-29 19:46:35');


SELECT * FROM "Items"
WHERE "TDate" <@ tsrange('[2020-01-20 00:00:00 , 2020-01-30)') 
--//Included lowerbound and excluded upper bound -- Valid values 2020-01-20 00:00:00 to 2020-01-29 23:59:59
ORDER BY "TDate" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In the text form of a range, an inclusive lower bound is represented by "[" while an exclusive lower bound is represented by "(". Likewise, an inclusive upper bound is represented by "]", while an exclusive upper bound is represented by ")"

---

**The result in PgAdmin4 connected to a PostgreSQL 10 instance**

[image: Code]

---

**References:**

- [Range Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html)
- [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html)

Comment: You really shouldn't use those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: There no problem using double quoted identifier. It depends of needs or style, for example in C# properties in class needs to be mapped in database with exactly name using "EntityFramework Core".